# changing value of <input type=file">

Tags: html, input

I want to know how to programmatically change the value of `<input type="file">`

I know that this is disabled for security reasons, but is there a workaround for it. I am using PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there was a workaround that works now, it certainly will be disabled in the future. As you said yourself, you cannot change the value of an file input element due to security restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't a workaround for it. It would be a pretty rubbish security measure if there was.