# PHP Curl to post data instead of <input type="file">

Tags: php, html, curl

I am currently using `<input type="file">` to post a file. Since I cant specify the value for

`<input id="content" type="file">` and have to manually browse for the file, I want to know if I can specify the path using PHP Curl.

will the server read `$_POST["content"]`

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to write a PHP program that will make an HTTP request and include a file encoded using multipart/form-data in the request? Thus bypassing the form itself altogether?

Comment: A related question just asked by the same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120084/changing-value-of-input-type-file

Comment: @Quentin Yes thats what i'm trying to do

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel — This appears to be a different question. The last one was "How can I prefill a file input?", this is "How can I post a file using PHP instead of a browser?" (Presumably with PHP running on the same machine as the file is starting on).

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Read the question before jumping to any conclusions.

Comment: @Quentin too many assumptions :) What makes you become an advocate for the OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it this way:

```
$post_params = array();
$post_params['file'] = '@'.'demo/testfile.txt';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
```

the **@** is really important to specify that this is an actual file to curl

You will receive the file through the $_FILES super global as if you did a rel form

```
$_FILES['file']
```

Hope it helps

To answer your question you need the absolute path on your filesystem

Comment: demo/testfile.txt is the relative path or absolute path? my file exists in c:\abc.doc

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted (unless it was due to the missing `curl_exec`). I would upvote if I was more familier with PHP's cURL library and could be more certain it was right.

Comment: If that is true (I'm not the downvoter), then the question makes a 540 degree turn in terms of technologies in use. @user478636: Have you intended that with your question?

Comment: To answer your question you need the absolute path on your filesystem