# Prevent file loading

Tags: javascript, input-type-file

I have `<input type="file" onchange="isValidFile(this.value)" />`.

```
function isValidFile(filename)
{
     if (getExtension(filename)!=srt)
     {
          //Don't load the file
     }
}
```

When you load a file the label of `<input type="file" />` change to filename, this show that file is loaded/selected, I want if the file have wrong extension to not load it and leave the label blank. I tried to change the value but read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120084/changing-value-of-input-type-file) that its not possible for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="abc">
    <input type="file" onchange="isValidFile(this.value)"/>
</form>

<script>
    function isValidFile(filename) {
        if (getExtension(filename) != 'jpg') {
            document.forms['abc'].reset();
            alert("invalid Image");
        }
    }
    function getExtension(filename) {
        return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    }
</script>
```

**Try this**

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use jquery ui validation plugin for validating the input type file?

http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/

please check the url for more information.

Comment: ya, I think jquery could help his problem

Comment: my problem is not validation

Comment: then you should first save all the form values in an object array then reset your form and after then reassign values to the input fields except file field.